# Why to use node pointer when creating a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
}
```

Why we can't use like below:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    int* next;
}
```

Why we have to create the pointer of type Node? We can also create a pointer of int type as address passed would be same in both cases.

Comment: Because the next element is a `struct Node` and not an `int`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Thanks for editing Jabber. Yeah, I agree that the next element is a node but to reach that address, we can also use the address of the next node's integer because the node address starts from there.

Comment: Yes you could do that, but why? It would make everything more complicated.

Comment: No, I was just having this doubt if the way I was thinking is correct or not. Thanks Anyways @Jabberwocky

Comment: Why use any types at all? Why use C even? Just write assembly, where everything is just raw data with no additional semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Because the struct node needs memory allocation:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

struct Node{
 int data;
 struct Node* next;
};
struct Node* head = NULL;

void push(struct Node **node_ref, int data){
struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
newNode->data = data;
newNode->next = (*node_ref);
(*node_ref) = newNode;
}
void displayList(struct Node* e){
    e = head;
    while(e != 0){
     printf("%d ", e->data);
     e = e->next;
    }
}
int main(){
head = NULL;
push(&head, 1);
push(&head, 2);
push(&head, 3);
displayList(head);
return 0;
}
```

The struct node should be same with head struct, cause in C can't convert struct if object is different.

Comment: The question is tagged C, not C++

Comment: @Jabberwocky check it sir

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C. And an answer should be properly formatted.

Comment: oh yes, I'm too used to using cpp

Comment: And in C++ you shouldn't use malloc.

Comment: @ZetaCan you please help me to share some resources with me to learn C++ for game development? Actually, I am good at java and python but want to learn C++ now. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: @ZetaI compiled and run the program but it keep running and giving garbage values. I used codeblocks and copy your code there and run it. please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: @bhishmsharma Sorry, I can't be of much help. maybe you have to take an online course or learn about the Unreal Engine on the official website, it is available for free.

Comment: @bhishmsharma the code is looping, i use repeat until.
do{
}while(n!= 10); << this is looping

Comment: @Zeta The problem is in your second loop because when the code prints the linked list, it showing garbage value and keep going on. I have to end the execution manually.

Comment: @bhishmsharma if you want learn C++ language for Game Developer. you can visit here [Unreal Engine Course](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/onlinelearning-courses)

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are classified in two types. Typed and untyped.
Typed pointer points to a specific type such as integer, float, char.

like `int* next; // this pointer points to an integer.`

Untyped pointer points to any kind of data type.

`struct node *next; // this points to a struct node data type which is the type of the next node.`

Because the pointer of the previous node holds the data type of the next node and here the data type of every node is of struct node.